# Java 8 Map with optional key to map with value of optional as key

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, collectors

I have a Map<Optional, String> and need to get a map with the actual values of the optionals, if they are present (Map<Price, String>).

This works:

```
private Map<Price, String> getPricesForUserRelatedPrices(List<SpecialPrice> prices) {
    Map<Optional<Price>, String> pricesWithOptional = prices.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(this::getPrice, this::getName));
    Map<Price, String> existingPrices = pricesWithOptional .entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().isPresent()).collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().get(), Entry::getValue));
    return existingPrices;
}
```

The getPrice might return an optional, therefore the empty entries need to be filtered.

The Map with the optional as key is of course only a temporary map to have it somewhat readable.

In the old fashioned/ non-lambda way I would just do this:

```
private Map<Price, String> getPricesForUserRelatedPrices(List<SpecialPrice> prices) {
Map<Price, String> existingPrices = new HashMap<>();
for(SpecialPrice p: prices){
    Optional<Price> price = getPrice(p);
    if(price.isPresent())
        existingPrices.put(price.get(), getName(price));
}
return existingPrices;
```

}

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Does Optional.empty == Optional. empty? If so, you may as well do getPrice().get() directly. The entire concept is broken if your Optionals can be empty.

Comment: Is Map<Optional<Price>, String> pricesWithOptional used somewhere or you just wanted to use it to take values again? If so, you can directly filter before collecting and skip the first step

Comment: Are you starting with `pricesWithOptional` already present? Or are you building that as part of your process? If the latter then you could just add a filter to `prices.stream()`.

Comment: To be honest using a `Optional` as a `Map` key seems a bit strange. I would suggest considering reworking the source and not use `Optional` in the first place.

Comment: Consider adding the definition of `prices` - its type is not clear.  You may also want to add the `Price` class.  In general, using an Optional as a key seems sketchy.  Perhaps you should filter out the elements that are not present and map to the price value?  Does a mapping of price-to-name really what you want?  It implies that only one item may have a given price - the manager at the dollar store is going to have a heart attack!

Comment: The `Collectors.toMap()` default implementation uses the `HashMap` class for the created map. This map implementation allows `null` keys, so you can remove the `filter()` operation of the stream and change `e -> e.getKey().get()` to `e -> e.getKey().get().orElse(null)`. Finally you can remove the `null` key of the resulting map if it is present. This sounds a little bit weird but it avoids calling `isPresent()` for each element in the map, therefore is a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is an alternate only if you completely discard `pricesWithOptional` after you have derived `existingPrices` and that is a step back from where you have already reached.

```
Map<Price, String> existingPrices = prices.stream()
        .map(p -> Map.entry(getPrice(p), getName(p))) // to avoid multiple calls to these
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().isPresent())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey().get(),
                Map.Entry::getValue));
```

**Note**: If both `getPrice` and `getName` are costly and you would likely not make `getName` unless you are sure of `getPrice`'s presence, I would rather suggest staying with the `for` loop for readability.

```
Map<Price, String> existingPrices = new HashMap<>();
for (SpecialPrice specialPrice : prices) {
    Optional<Price> price = getPrice(specialPrice);
    if (price.isPresent()) {
        String name = getName(specialPrice);
        existingPrices.put(price.get(), name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to [@Naman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67724883/12983647):

If `getName` is costly and you want to keep the functional style, you can defer the invocation to the collection phase:

```java
private Map<Price, String> getPricesForUserRelatedPrices(List<SpecialPrice> prices) {
        return prices.stream()
            .map(p -> Map.entry(getPrice(p), p))
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().isPresent())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey().get(),
                entry -> getName(entry.getValue())));
    }
```